# Execute immediate select returns no values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have select statement

```
select name, surname
from student
where id_student = 1;
```

It returns

```
name surname
Bob Smith
```

I want to create procedure with same select statement, using execute immediate:

```
create or replace procedure select_procedure
as
begin
execute immediate
'select name, surname
from student
where id_student = 1';
end;
/
exec select_procedure;
```

When this procedure is executed it shows PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. How do I get the result? (set serveroutput is on)

Answer (score 5):

You have to select *into* something. If you don't then the query [isn't even executed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8__GUID-03324D0E-5267-42B9-98BE-8325F9213352) (though it is parsed).

```
create or replace procedure select_procedure
as
  l_name student.name%TYPE;
  l_surname student.name%TYPE;
begin
  execute immediate
  'select name, surname
  from student
  where id_student = 1'
  into l_name, l_surname;
end;
/
```

But, in no particular order: (a) you should use bind variables instead of having the literal value 1 embedded in the dynamic statement; (b) this doesn't need to be dynamic at all; and (c) the caller won't be able to see the values returned by the query anyway - unless you select into `OUT` arguments instead, or display them with `dbms_output()` (although that should really only be used for debugging as you can't control whether the client will show it).

So you could do:

```
create or replace procedure select_procedure
as
  l_name student.name%TYPE;
  l_surname student.name%TYPE;
begin
  select name, surname
  into l_name, l_surname
  from student
  where id_student = 1;

  dbms_output.put_line('name=' || l_name ||', surname=' || l_surname);
end;
/
```

or

```
create or replace procedure select_procedure (
  p_name OUT student.name%TYPE,
  p_surname OUT student.name%TYPE
)
as
begin
  select name, surname
  into p_name, p_surname
  from student
  where id_student = 1;
end;
/
```

and have your caller pass in its own variable names to populate, and then do whatever it needs with those. The caller would usually also pass in the ID you're looking for, so you don't have the 1 hard-coded.

It doesn't seem like a procedure is really the best mechanism for this though.

Also, using a `select ... into` (static or dynamic) will error if the query returns  zero rows or more than one row. It will only work if there is exactly one row returned. A cursor would handle any number of rows - but unless you are just printing the results (as @Jayanth shows) you need to pass the cursor back to the caller instead. You could do a `bulk collect into` a collection instead, but you still have to do something with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a cursor for this.Please find below the syntax for the same.

**Syntax:**

```
create or replace procedure select_procedure
as
CURSOR <cursor_name> IS <SELECT statement without semicolon>;
BEGIN
  FOR record IN <cursor_name>
  LOOP
  Dbms_output.put_line(‘Record Fetched:‘||record.name);
  Dbms_output.put_line(‘Record Fetched:‘||record.surname);
  END LOOP;
END;
```